# Unable to access a global array declared in another translation unit via pointer

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I am working in embedded domain and using Zephyr RTOS for development.
I am facing a null pointer while trying to access an array declared in another source file via pointer.

protocol.c

```
uint8_t buffer[5];
...
void prepare_payload_data(uint8_t* buf)
{
     buf = buffer;
     buf[0] = 0x02;
     ...
     buf[4] = 0x0A;   
}
```

I have a header file protocol.h, in which I have a declaration for  prepare_payload_data().

protocol.h

```
void prepare_payload_data(uint8_t* buf);
```

Now in some other file, I am trying to use prepare_payload_data in following way:
transfer_data.c

```
#include "protocol.h"
#include <sys/printk.h>

uint8_t* data_buffer = NULL;
...
prepare_payload_data(data_buffer);
if(!data_buffer)
{
    printk("Buffer is null \n");  /*Getting this printed on console*/
}
```

I am not sure what am I doing wrong here. What is preventing me from accessing the buffer declared in protocol.c

But when I move the buffer to transfer_data.c, then everything works fine.

protocol.c

```
void prepare_payload_data(uint8_t* buf)
{
     buf[0] = 0x02;
     ...
     buf[4] = 0x0A;   
}
```

transfer_data.c

```
#include "protocol.h"
#include <sys/printk.h>

uint8_t buffer[5];
...
prepare_payload_data(buffer);
if(!buffer)
{
    printk("Buffer is null \n");  /*Not getting this printed*/
}
```

Comment: Changing the parameter `buf` in `prepare_payload_data` does not change the argument in the calling function,

Answer (score 0):

`void prepare_payload_data(uint8_t* buf)` passes the pointer *by value*, so you can't do `buf = buffer;` from inside the function and expect `data_buffer` in the caller to change. For the same reason as this:

```
void f (int x)
{
  x = 5;
}
```

will not change the integer passed from the caller. This has nothing to do with translation units, it's just how functions work. If you wish to change where the pointer points at, then either pass a pointer to pointer parameter `uint8_t**` or return a pointer from the function.